# MySQL Client, Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, sqlite

I've gone through a lot of posts but still haven't found the right solution to it yet. I'm using Windows Server to try and connect MySQL with Django. I want to transfer the data from my SQLite db to MySQL db.

I've already installed MySQL client, made changes to my Settings.py and everything. I've linked my MySQL to my phpMyAdmin as well. I'm still a beginner and this is the first time I'm trying to do anything of this sort.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker>pip install mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient==1.3.12 from file:///C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/BugTracker/mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl in c:\program files\python37\lib\s
ite-packages (1.3.12)

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker>









python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\Bugs\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Bugs(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 114, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker>cd C:\Program Files\MySQL

(venv) C:\Program Files\MySQL>pip install mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient==1.3.12 from file:///C:/Program%20Files/MySQL/mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (1.3.12)

(venv) C:\Program Files\MySQL>python manage.py migrate
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

(venv) C:\Program Files\MySQL>cd C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker>pip install mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient==1.3.12 from file:///C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/BugTracker/mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl in c:\program files\python37\lib\s
ite-packages (1.3.12)

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker>pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysql-python ... error
  Complete output from command "c:\program files\python37\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v3b7qmf2\\mysql-python
\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp
\pip-wheel-dbge4tbc --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__versi
on__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visu
al Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\uc
rt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\
10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(192): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefinition
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(276): note: see previous definition of 'isnan'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203): warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': macro redefinition
  c:\program files\python37\include\pyconfig.h(304): note: see previous definition of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301): warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H': macro redefinition
  c:\program files\python37\include\pyconfig.h(593): note: see previous definition of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
  _mysql.c(287): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(297): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(317): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(327): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(470): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(623): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(624): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(625): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(626): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(627): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1118): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1161): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1162): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1165): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1274): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1466): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1468): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1504): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1506): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1532): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
  _mysql.c(2238): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ConnectionObject *' to 'long'
  _mysql.c(2241): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ConnectionObject *' to 'long'
  _mysql.c(2302): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from '__int64' to 'long', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(2321): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ResultObject *' to 'long'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LI
BPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" "/LIBPATH:c:\program files\python37\libs" "/LIBPATH:c:\program files\python37\PCbuild\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86
)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows K
its\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64" kernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__mysql build\te
mp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.lib
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.exp
  mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(viosslfactories.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_messnc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_thr_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
  build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysql-python
  Running setup.py clean for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files\python37\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v3b7qmf2\\mysql-pyth
on\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\
Temp\pip-record-2gvkmozv\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__ver
sion__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Vi
sual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\
ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\includ
e\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(192): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefinition
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(276): note: see previous definition of 'isnan'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203): warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': macro redefinition
    c:\program files\python37\include\pyconfig.h(304): note: see previous definition of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301): warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H': macro redefinition
    c:\program files\python37\include\pyconfig.h(593): note: see previous definition of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
    _mysql.c(287): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(297): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(317): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(327): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(470): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(623): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(624): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(625): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(626): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(627): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1118): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1161): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1162): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1165): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1274): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1466): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1468): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1504): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1506): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1532): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
    _mysql.c(2238): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ConnectionObject *' to 'long'
    _mysql.c(2241): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ConnectionObject *' to 'long'
    _mysql.c(2302): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from '__int64' to 'long', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(2321): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from '_mysql_ResultObject *' to 'long'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/
LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" "/LIBPATH:c:\program files\python37\libs" "/LIBPATH:c:\program files\python37\PCbuild\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x
86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64" kernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__mysql build\
temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.lib
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.exp
    mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(viosslfactories.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_messnc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_thr_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
    build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files\python37\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v3b7qmf2\\mysql-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(
tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2gvkmozv
\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v3b7qmf2\mysql-python\

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker>







(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\Bugs\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Bugs(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 114, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker>
```

UPDATE: It shows that theres an error after the "except ImportError as err:" part

```
try:
    import MySQLdb as Database
except ImportError as err:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
        'Error loading MySQLdb module.\n'
        'Did you install mysqlclient?'
    ) from err
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: you have installed mysqlclient to your system python (`c:\program files\python37\lib\s
ite-packages`), but you're trying to run `python manage.py syncdb` from a virtualenv (`C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\BugTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django...`). All packages need to be installed to the same Python environment if you want to use them together.

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining that there is no module named 'MySQLdb'. You have to install MySQLdb by running command:

pip install MySQL-python

Comment: Throws an error... I cant Post the error here because it'll Exceed the limit

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: 
Download the pre-compiled whl file for mysql-python from from Christophe Gohlke’s site:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

Go to downloaded path and

Now run below command pip install xxx.whl

If above doesnot work 
install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python from

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

and install client driver for connection from here

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=378015

Comment: When I try to migrate, it shows me the same error.. 
Ive installed MySQL Connector C 6.0.2, MySQL Server 5.5, mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: have you configured ODBC as well
steps here : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/administer-odbc-data-sources-b19f856b-5b9b-48c9-8b93-07484bfab5a7

Comment: What files do I add and which one do I add to? User DSN, System DSN or File DSN?

Comment: It Shows that theres an error in this part of my base.py


Check my post for the latest update

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

1. `brew install mysql-client`
2. `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
3. `source ~/.bash_profile`
4. `pip install mysqlclient`